# Function properties preserved under a change of metrics?

Tags: functions, metric-spaces, continuity, normed-spaces

Consider two metric spaces $(X, d_X)$ and $(Y,d_Y)$, with $d_X$ and $d_Y$ induced by two norms. Suppose function $f: X → Y$ has or lacks some properties, such as:

1. Continuity
2. Uniform Continuity
3. Lipschitz Continuity with constant K
4. Contraction mapping
5. Differentiabiliy

Now suppose we replace $d_X$ and $d_Y$ by metrics $d_{X}'$ and $d_{Y}'$, where $d_{X}'$ and $d_{Y}'$ are induced by norms that are equivalent to those that induced $d_X$ and $d_Y$.

Does the function $f$ possess the same properties (1-5) with these new metrics?

I found it surprisingly hard to figure out if that is the case - most sources I've seen just prove that all norms are equivalent in a finite-dimensional linear space, without really showing why we would care for norm equivalence at all.

EDIT: It doesn't work for Lipschitz Continuity [as described here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2822493/lipschitz-constant-of-a-function-preserved-under-equivalent-metrics/2822540#2822540).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Equivalent norms induce the same open sets — so $(X, d_X)$ and $(X, d_X')$ have the same underlying *topological space*.

So, anything that can be expressed in terms of *topology* respects equivalence of norms. For example:

- [Continuity of a function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function#Continuous_functions_between_topological_spaces) has a simple description in terms of open sets,
- [Uniform continuity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_continuity#Generalization_to_topological_vector_spaces) can be defined on topological vector spaces.

Comment: Thank you! Very helpful.